# How can LocationMatch and ProxyPassMatch be Combined?

Tags: apache, proxypass, locationmatch

I am setting up an Apache 2.4.6 server on an internal machine for testing purposes. One of the things that Apache server is supposed to do is act as a reverse-proxy for another server found on localhost:3030.

The server on localhost:3030 expects one out of a few dataset names on its first path level (for now, the set comprises only of the dataset `experimental`, but some more will be added later on), so I am trying to pass that through from the requested path.

In my vhost, this works:

```
<Location /experimental/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3030/experimental/
    ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

For additional datasets, I could copy that and replace `experimental` with the other dataset names. Obviously, that leads to a lot of code duplication/redundancy, which is both a source of errors and a maintenance horror.

Therefore, I would like to become somewhat more flexible and treat several datasets in a single such block. This should be possible with the [`LocationMatch` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#locationmatch).

As indicated by [this comment](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/pull/121) and [this page](http://keita.flagship.cc/2013/06/04/locationmatch-and-proxypass/), I need to replace [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) [`ProxyPassMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) when using that inside a `LocationMatch` block. Essentially, the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) state the same:

> The same will occur inside a LocationMatch section, however ProxyPass does not interpret the regexp as such, so it is necessary to use ProxyPassMatch in this situation instead.

The [`LocationMatch` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#locationmatch) explain:

> From 2.4.8 onwards, named groups and backreferences are captured and written to the environment with the corresponding name prefixed with "MATCH_" and in upper case. This allows elements of URLs to be referenced from within expressions and modules like mod_rewrite. In order to prevent confusion, numbered (unnamed) backreferences are ignored. Use named groups instead.

That information is only valid as of Apache 2.4.8, which is presumeably why the following does not work on my 2.4.6 installation:

```
<LocationMatch /(?<dataset>experimental)/>
    ProxyPassMatch http://localhost:3030/%{env:MATCH_DATASET}/
    ProxyPassReverse /
</LocationMatch>
```

On the other hand, [this page](http://keita.flagship.cc/2013/06/04/locationmatch-and-proxypass/) and [that posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/railo/3ai5H31uDos/a6JA5w0WnHQJ) imply that the numerical group index (`$1`) can be used (as the help text is valid only as of httpd 2.4.8, my *suspicion* / *hope* is that the numerical reference works before 2.4.8 (?)

In any case, I have tried this:

```
<LocationMatch "/(experimental)/">
    ProxyPassMatch http://localhost:3030/$1/
    ProxyPassReverse /
</LocationMatch>
```

yet according to the logs, the internal call invokes `http://localhost:3030/$1/` instead of `http://localhost:3030/experimental/` when requesting the `experimental` path on the vhost URL.

The [`ProxyPassMatch` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) only say:

> When used inside a LocationMatch section, the first argument is omitted and the regexp is obtained from the LocationMatch.

However, the text does not bother to provide an example for how to combine `LocationMatch` and `ProxyPassMatch`. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Numbered backreferences are ignored with ```LocationMatch```: ```In order to prevent confusion, numbered (unnamed) backreferences are ignored. Use named groups instead.``` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch

Comment: Actually this bug might be more relevant to your question: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50048

Answer (score 4):

The doc also states `When the URL parameter doesn't use any backreferences into the regular expression, the original URL will be appended to the URL parameter.`, which seems to be your case.
Further more, you are missing the host in your  `ProxyPassReverse` directive.

This should work just fine:

```
<LocationMatch "^/experimental/.*$">
    ProxyPassMatch http://localhost:3030
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3030
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got this working on Apache 2.4.29:

```
<LocationMatch "/fruit/(?:apple|banana|pear)">
    ProxyPass        http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080
</LocationMatch>
```

The URL called by Apache is for example

```
http://localhost:8080/fruit/apple
```

The `(?:` is crucial when you are using parentheses in this example.

Comment: This works nicely but why `(?:` is crucial?

Comment: @SamuliAsmala Without `(?:` it will probably only pass the part matching between the parentheses, for example `apple` to the proxy server