# How to pass captured group to BalanceMember using LocationMatch

Tags: apache, locationmatch

I'm using Apache 2.4.37. I'm trying to capture part of a URL using LocationMatch and then append just the captured value to a BalanceMember entry.

Given a URL pattern like this...

```
https://someserver.com/some/path/:id/:moreStuff
```

id is a multi-character string. If it ends in a 0, I want everything in the URL after "some/path" sent to one place; else I want it sent to another place.

For example, a request to `https://someserver.com/some/path/10/foo` would go to `https://someotherserver.com/new/path/10/foo`; whereas a request to `https://someserver.com/some/path/11/foo` would go to `https://someotherserver.com/other/path/11/foo`

My first failed attempt...

```
# Catch-all to handle requests where id does not end in 0
<Location /some/path
  ProxyPass "balancer://other_path_balancer"
  ProxyPassReverse "balancer://other_path_balancer"
</Location>
<Proxy "balancer://other_path_balancer">
  BalancerMember https://someotherserver.com/other/path
</Proxy>

# Handle all requests where id ends in 0
<LocationMatch "^/some/path/(.*0/.*$)"
  ProxyPass "balancer://new_path_balancer"
  ProxyPassReverse "balancer://new_path_balancer"
</LocationMatch>
<Proxy "balancer://new_path_balancer">
  BalancerMember https://someotherserver.com/new/path
</Proxy>
```

But my example using id 10 ends up going to `https://someotherserver.com/new/path/some/path/10/foo`. I.e.
It's appending the entire match from LocationMatch, not just the capture.

So I tried changing the LocationMatch to use a named group with a back reference...

```
<LocationMatch "^/some/path/(?<partIwant>.*0/.*$)"
  ProxyPass "balancer://new_path_balancer"
  ProxyPassReverse "balancer://new_path_balancer"
</LocationMatch>
<Proxy "balancer://new_path_balancer">
  BalancerMember https://someotherserver.com/new/path/%{ENV:MATCH_PARTIWANT}
</Proxy>
```

but this attempt yielded a request to  `https://someotherserver.com/new/path/%{ENV:MATCH_PARTIWANT}/some/path/10`. I.e. The %{ENV:MATCH_PARTIWANT} didn't get evaluated.

I based my attempts on what I've read at [How can LocationMatch and ProxyPassMatch be Combined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548631/how-can-locationmatch-and-proxypassmatch-be-combined) and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch